# I can not run the servlet in Tomchat 7.0.90

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm new to Java. I make my first servlet in Intellij Idea 2018.2.1.([in this screen my idea project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xdqK.jpg)) I do as instructed from here:
http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/javaservlets.html

I created all the directories, as it says in the tooltip, created and compiled the class HelloServlet.java and put it in the desired directory ([in this screen my my Tomcat directory with my class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6YT9.jpg)), created and filled the web.xml file[here my web.xml and it's Tomcat path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnIkl.jpg). But when I try to call it in a browser string "http://localhost:8080/helloservlet/sayhello" (as stated in the instruction) I get an error [in this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USQyG.jpg).

What am i do wrong? What i need to do to solve this issue?

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-ee-application.html. You need a web project with WAR artifact deployment.

Comment: If you are new to Java, then please run a mode recent version of Tomcat. he current version is 9.0.x, not 7.0.x.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved. Unfortunatelly, i understand wrong my instructuion, i need to put HelloServlet.class in this path "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\helloservlet\WEB-INF\classes\mypkg", no this file - HelloServlet.java. Now all works correctly. Thank's to all.